# Who should a StackOverflow question belong to?

Tags: discussion

I recently had an edit come in to the title of one of my questions.

**My original title**: "Is there a more elegant way to express ((x == a and y == b) or (x == b and y == a))?"

**Another user's revised title**: "More elegant way to express ((x == a and y == b) or (x == b and y == a))?"

At first, I was annoyed. I thought my original title was fine, and I decided to revert the edit. But after thinking about it more, I can see why the person edited the title and that I was only annoyed since someone edited something that I viewed as being "mine" and they did so without my permission. I think this is human nature!

This got me thinking about who a StackOverflow question belongs to. Who should get to be the arbiter of edit disputes?

It seems to me that StackOverflow is currently setup in the same manner as a wiki. Nearly anyone can edit the questions (provided they meet the fairly easy minimum requirements) and the original creator of the question doesn't have the ability to *prevent* edits. **In this sense, I would say that the current situation with StackOverflow is such that the community owns the questions.**

**However, I would argue that StackOverflow would be a much more friendly environment for people if they could control their own questions**, at least to some greater degree than they currently can. And if their question is suboptimally written and they don't want people editing it, then so be it. And if they want to allow people to edit their questions, then great. Let's give them the ability to choose.

For example, I think it'd feel better for the asker if they could optionally choose to stop edits once some amount of time has passed since the question was submitted. The tradeoff here is that it would feel worse for the COMMUNITY, since such a change would lead to them having to endure questions being in a state that they'd like to edit. But why should an asker's question belong to the community? I think it should belong to the asker.

So the core question I'm raising for discussion is, "Who should a StackOverflow question belong to?"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/08/in-defense-of-editing/

Comment: You can **always** revert edits. I don't think giving people a chance to "lock" their question makes sense, honestly. You always have the "final" word for a Stack question if it's yours (as long as it's on topic, non offensive, etc). But... the intent of Stack if to be a long term repository of knowledge (wiki wasn't a bad analogy, even if it's far from perfect). With that in mind, editing, polishing pearls, is always a good move for us to do.

Comment: @HansPassant I did read that and I understand StackOverflow's current position on this. What I want to discuss is what the community thinks it should be like.

Comment: @Patrice I understand that's the intent of StackOverflow. What I'm raising for discussion is whether or not that intent should be revised. We know that newcomers to the site report feeling unwelcomed and I believe this question of who a question belongs to is at the very core of that situation.

Comment: Logically, if users refuse to allow their questions to be edited, the community has to have the option to refuse them prior to posting.  Which is more unwelcoming: trying to make a question the best it can, and the poster losing some agency on it, or refusing to accept some in the first place?  Don't forget the original motivation for asking it here in the first place: they need help, and so agree to the requirements here in order to post it.

Comment: In this particular case, I agree with you in that I don't get why the title needed to be edited or how the new version was any better. But more generally, community editing is a core part of the site philosophy and isn't going anywhere.

Comment: It's interesting to read people's opinions on this so far. The consensus seems to be, "This is just how StackOverflow is and will always be." And I get that standpoint, but consider a higher vantage point. If a competitor came in and did what StackOverflow does, except with giving the user full control over their questions, then would people want to use StackOverflow or that competitor more? I suspect people would prefer to SEARCH for answers to existing questions on SO, since the quality of questions and answers would be higher, but would prefer to ASK questions on the competitor's site.

Comment: *"I suspect people would [...] prefer to ASK questions on the competitor's site"* ... based on what? The "who dares to edit my post"-people may switch, but seeing how many people actually accept edits during review vs people rejecting/reverting edits, it will hardly be a significant mass.

Comment: Stack has been told it's too negative for years now. the "threat" of 'another site will do it better!' has been out for as long as the "you're too negative"... and I must say, I don't see it happening. I get your point. Stack could do better at being *perceived* less negatively. To me that comes from a proper set of expectations *when a new user joins*. Not from a "let's lower the bar of everything for the lowest common denominator"

Comment: So if you ever misspell "func" as "fu**" you suggest that the only action community should do is flag you post "rude or abusive"? Fine by me but it would be very hard to explain why one single mistake will land you on "no longer accepting …  from this account" list... Editing lets such things to be fixed quickly without drastic measures as removal of post from the site.

Comment: Think Wikipedia, not Twitter.

Comment: The percentage of questions that get edited right away is pretty high. Newish users are terrible at code formatting, non native English speakers have understandable grammar issues, some native speakers can't format proper sentences....the valid reasons to edit  are many. People who review lots of questions prefer them to have a reasonable structure. Lots of people are pedantic about grammar, language constructs and spelling also. Have to remember that the questions are all part of the greater knowledge base

Answer (score 10):

If this change happened instantly - that is, you didn't get a chance to *review* the change - then that person has full editing privileges, and is trusted by the system to make these kinds of changes.

If this change showed up on your question but hadn't really taken effect (e.g. someone suggested an edit to your post but it wasn't live), then that person doesn't have full editing privileges and would have to have it peer reviewed by others.

The site is **built on this**; people who edit posts generally don't try and put words in the OP's mouth, but instead they try and re-form a part of the post to make it read easier.  If someone *did* completely change what you were saying, then that's grounds to roll back the edit.

Posts are not "owned" in the formal sense that you can forbid anyone from editing the content, and neither should they be.  Editing can make a world of difference between someone having an okay but unclear question closed and downvoted, versus someone having an okay but unclear question edited to be *more* clear and upvoted.